# Jasper Server Scheduled Email

Tags: jasperserver

I recently try to Generate the Report from Jasper Server. But I didn't receive emailed report from my schedule. Even I did changes in js.quartz.properties file and application.context.report.schedule.xml file. I didn't use any framework for my project. I want to Generate Mailed report from my Database as per Schedule.

Can you Please give me a Solution for this?

I want to Generate my Report as per my Schedule in Jasper Server.